# Pact Pattern Matching

Tags: design-patterns, matcher, pact

I need some help to write a Pact Regular Expression Pattern Matching test for the below json. I am struggling to write for Account and AdditionalInfo

```
{
    "Account": [
        {
            "ContractId": "679",
            "Code": "0000",

        }
    ],
    "AdditionalInfo": [
        {
            "Contract`enter code here`Id": "679,
            "errorMessage": "NOT CARRIED OUT"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi praneeth. To help folks understand your request, please show some code you have tried.

Comment: Could you explain more about what you want the regex to match?

Comment: Hi Praneeth, please share the full context of how you are authoring your Pact tests already. We also need to know what language you are using (e.g. Java, JS, Go etc.). Here is an example for JS that matches on complex objects including Arrays https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js#match-based-on-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [EachLike](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-python#eachlikematcher-minimum1)?

```
{
"Account": EachLike(
    {
        "ContractId": "679",
        "Code": "0000",

    }
),
"AdditionalInfo": EachLike(
    {
        "Contract`enter code here`Id": "679,
        "errorMessage": "NOT CARRIED OUT"
    }
)
```

}